# get data from [object object] in templates ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to read data from a response in my Template which is an array of objects. 
[image]

Now I want to get the data using the index. I tried the below code butI'm not able to get the data.

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col class="colomn">
        Vacation
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        {{leaves[0].id}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

But it's throwing error `cannot read property id of undefined`. How can I get the values from the object?

Query :
Can you let me know how I can get the created _at date from the below data
[image]
Below answers are not working for this.

Comment: Please post your ts file and HTML file of the page .. so we could get a better understanding of the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the leaves variable as an array like below.

```
leaves: any[] = []
```

In your template use like this.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col class="colomn">
       Vacation
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
       {{leaves[0]?.id}}
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Another way is, use ***ngIf**

```
<ion-row *ngIf="leaves.length > 0">
     <ion-col class="colomn">
        Vacation
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col>
        {{leaves[0].id}}
     </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Hey the answer worked for that format can you let me know how to get created at date value. I have updated my question with the format of my data. @Ajantha Bandara